# how to make i18next uses Spring MVC message Resources

Tags: spring, internationalization, i18next

I'm developing an SPA with Backbone, using Marionette and Handlebars, also Spring MVC. We need i18n support both in templates and Spring Controllers. Someone has recommended me i18next  for Handlebars templates.

The problem is that i18next needs a JSON message source, and Spring uses properties files.

¿There is any way that both (Spring and i18next) of them share the same Message source?. I can change i18next for another component, if it makes it work.

Comment: You can create a controller which dumps the content of the `MessageSource` properties file as a json object.